# Opencv height/width of part of image

Tags: c++, opencv, contour, bounding-box, image-stitching

I've an image like this one ![enter image description here][1]. The non-black part is expanded at each iteration. So, after a certain point, I need to enlarge the final image so the non-black one can fit in. For now, what I'm doing is to find the contour of the non-black image,find the bounding box of the contours and check the width/height of the box. At a first time it works, but after some iterations my program finds a bounding box of size 1 (it seems that it doesn't find any contour). What the problem could be?

Ps: the program is a mosaic from a video file, I followed the opencv tutorial for find homography and other stuff.

***EDIT***
Sorry but I had to remove images

Comment: Did you apply [threshold](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=threshold#threshold) for the non-black pixels before finding contours?

Comment: Yes, first I was using Canny, then I switch to threshold!

Comment: Sorry for the double post, but do you think there's a faster way for finding contour/bounding box?

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion:

It's easier to simply iterate through each element in the matrix and record the coordinates of the uppermost, bottommost, leftmost and rightmost non-zero elements. These will be the four corners of your up-right bounding rectangle. Of course it is not necessarily the rectangle of the minimum area enclosing the non-zero pixels (not a rotated rectangle), but further can be used as a ROI.

Comment: I've found this for extract the extreme points http://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/d32/tutorial_py_contour_properties.html, but it's for python. There's a similar way to do it in c++? I'm sorry but I'm very new to opencv!

Comment: this is also based on `cv::findContours()`, but every function have C++ version too, i.e. [Tutorial - Bounding rects / circles](http://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d0c/tutorial_bounding_rects_circles.html)